# Problems using POST method in form to pass long parameters to URL

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, iframe

The URL that I am trying to access in an iframe has parameters that are over 2000 characters, which is way over the limit for browsers, therefore I am trying to hack around this by using a form with the method "post". However, the code below does not change the URL of my iframe upon pressing submit. If I change the form's method parameter to "get", then it does do the URL modification, however this is not of help as this doesn't allow me to pass my +2000-character parameters. Do some URL's not allow using the "post" method, or is there something I am missing in my code below?

```
<form id="longURL" target="myFrame"  action="http://localhost.com/" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="verylongstring">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<iframe name="myFrame" src="">
</iframe>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 var longURL= document.getElementById("longURL");
 longURL.submit();
});
</script>
```

Comment: POST params are not part of the URL.

Comment: Shouldn't it be  `... document.getElementById("id");` ?  if you want the value of the hidden input named id?

Comment: @PeterMader So is what I am trying to do impossible? Both GET and PUT work but they enforce character limits under the length of my parameters.

Comment: @DuaneLortie I am getting the form in order to submit it, so I think longURL is the correct ID there.